# How can I play media/video files via UPnP/DLNA from command line (DMC/DMP)

Tags: command-line, vlc, dlna, upnp

I am looking for something like `gupnp-av-cp` (or any other UPnP capable program/player/conntroller), but from the command line.

I would like to pass it a renderer and the URI of the file/resource.

It would be nice if it could handle local file resources (probably by starting up a temporary server?!)

Using VLC would be nice, but it does not appear to support via command line arguments, does it?